# road, curving vs road curving : comma with participial phrases

Tags: participial-adjectives

In the same quote below, why is the first occurrence of road is followed by a comma while the second is not? Who or what is curving in the first occurrence, the road or the writer? Can I get evidence as to who or what is curving from the text or grammar rules?

> I was on a high, open **road, curving over** the swell of hillside that I
>   saw as the flanks of some prehistoric animal, deep in slumber. The
>   moonlight was so strong as to throw my shadow beside me on the road as
>   a mute companion; and so I found myself not quite alone after all,
>   taking a childish pleasure in my shadow-self as it matched me stride
>   for stride. I could see quite clearly **my road curving ahead**, and the
>   clump of trees, inky black, that marked my turning point.

Source: [Chapter One of Set in Stone by Linda Newberry](https://www.banburyguardian.co.uk/news/chapter-one-of-set-in-stone-by-linda-newberry-1-588741)

Answer (score 1):

*curving over the swell of hillside that I saw as the flanks of some prehistorical animal, deep in slumber* is a participle clause modifying **road**.

Compare:

> On the plate was a scoop of ice-cream, melting under the heat of the sun.

and *curving ahead* is  an object-complement, when **road** is the direct object of **saw**.  It is like a secondary predicate.

> I saw the road <sup>[to be]</sup> curving ahead.

Compare:

> I heard her sneezing.
>
> I felt my left eye twitching.
>
> I smelled it burning on the stove.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tᴚoɯɐuo. Lost my comment due to power outage. +10 for object complement; I knew it has to do with the verb *see* but wasn't able to articulate it grammatically. This part is perfectly clear. As for the first occurrence of *road*, is the comma needed? If the comma was left out, how would that change the meaning? Contrary to the *complement*, I guess it has to do with it being non-essential information. For example, the melting is some info added to the original sentence and can go without it. Am I right?

Comment: Punctuation varies "in the wild" very greatly, and I, for one, do not grant that it determines meaning: it merely reflects the syntactic structures of the utterance and serves as a more or less reliable guide. Those structures are still present without punctuation, just not as evident to the eye. To the extent that readers allow themselves to be guided by punctuation, the absence of the comma in the first sentence could cause a hiccup of confusion, since it would admit the possibility of a present-progressive **I ... was curving**.  But that confusion would be cleared up momentarily.

Comment: Some people analyzing those sentences might not consider **sneezing, twitching**, and **burning** to be complements,  but I consider them not merely adjuncts but integral.

Comment: Thanks. "**the absence of the comma** in the first sentence could cause a hiccup of confusion, since it would admit the possibility of a present-progressive **I ... was curving**."

Comment: Some native speakers have already interpreted it with the present progressive form, **the writer is curving**-something I was dubious about.

Comment: Especially in literary works punctuation is not an arbiter because writers use it not only to demarcate clauses but to establish a sense of narrative pace and rhetorical pauses which may or may not coincide with major syntactic boundaries.